# Use struct pointer to assign array

Tags: c, arrays, windows

I have the following code

```
typedef struct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    }DATA;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DATA *N = NULL;
    unsigned char buff[65536];
    N = (DATA*)&buff;
    N->a = 1000;
    N->b = 50000;
    for(int i =0; i < 8; i ++)
        printf("buff[%d]: %d\n", i, buff[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which renders the following output:

```
buff[0]: 232

buff[1]: 3

buff[2]: 0

buff[3]: 0

buff[4]: 80

buff[5]: 195

buff[6]: 0

buff[7]: 0
```

Can anybody tell me in which way the `buff` Array got assigned ?

Comment: `1000 = 0*2^24 + 0*2^16 + 3*2^8 + 232` and `50000 = 0*2^24 + 0*2^16 + 195*2^8 + 80`. In this system, `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: What is this code for?

Comment: Are you asking why writing through the pointer modifies the memory buffer? Because you set the pointer to point to that buffer, treating it as a different type. Or are you asking why the integer values are represented by those particular byte values?

Comment: iharob A homework

lurker Thank you very much!!! :x

Comment: @MikeSeymour I want to ask why the integer values are represented by those particular byte values.

Comment: Look for [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), use hexadecimal output (`%x` instead of `%d`), keep in mind that 1000 and 50000 are 0x03e8 and 0xc350, resp., and I think you'll get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of pointers as type-size specifiers. A pointer is roughly an address associated with a size to consider when dereferencing. When declaring `int c = 2; int *p = &2;` you are associating the size of an int (say 4bytes) with an address the compiler will define. When you actually dereference p, `int x = *p`, the compiler knows you are trying to access 4bytes at address p.
Now, if you succeed in thinking of it this way, why your buffer gets filled this way will be as clear as ever. Your unsigned char array is a buffer of 65536 bytes. When you cast the address 'buff' into a (DATA *), you are specifying a new size (the size of type DATA) for dereferencing. Therefore, 1000 will be written on the 4bytes of N->a and 50000 on the 4bytes of N->b.
Now, 1000 in decimal is 3E8 in hex; since 4bytes need to be written, it will be sign extended and will be written bytes 00, 00, 03, E8, which in decimal is, as you would expect, bytes 0, 0, 3, 232. Now you might think they were written in reverse order, but this is because of endianess. Endianess is the way the processor actually writes bytes into memory, and in your case, your processor writes and reads bytes in reverse order, hence they are put in memory in this order. Same goes for N->b, as 50000 in decimal equals to the decimal bytes, 0, 0, 195, 80.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote two 4-byte integers into the buffer in [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format. The program is behaving exactly as expected.